# display Album Art into image view

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I want to load album art into image view but my code is not working and giving error, how to resolve my error?please help.

```
ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/Sqlit/AndroidDownloadManager.mp3");
    if (sArtworkUri !=null){
        MediaMetadataRetriever mData=new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mData.setDataSource(this,sArtworkUri);


        byte art[]=mData.getEmbeddedPicture();
        Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art,0,art.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    }
```

error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andriodtime.net/com.andriodtime.net.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                 at com.andriodtime.net.MainActivity.initView(MainActivity.java:91)
                                                                 at com.andriodtime.net.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
```

Comment: How you are calling **MainActivity.initView**..? Add your MainActivty onCreate Method.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I add to onCreate but has errored.I think this code is incorrect  **Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/Sqlit/AndroidDownloadManager.mp3");**

Comment: As per your log, It's crashing in **Line no 91**  you can check what is the line is doing. or you can add that line

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Line no 91 this code  **Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/Sqlit/AndroidDownloadManager.mp3");**

Comment: You are sending this(**"/sdcard/Sqlit/AndroidDownloadManager.mp3"**) string constant or you are getting some value and you are sending..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I am not sending,i want  get abum art from **("/sdcard/Sqlit/AndroidDownloadManager.mp3") **  and display from image view

Comment: Sorry, I would like to ask, are you parsing hard coded value? or you are parsed by using some variable..? because this is uri source code   **private StringUri(String uriString) {
            if (uriString == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("uriString");
            }

            this.uriString = uriString;
        }** if we send hard code value it will not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your application might not have permission to read from the SD Card.

You could add the following permission to your manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Note, that you'll probably have to request this permission at runtime.